# Querying json with RESTful API using Azure

Tags: json, azure, azure-web-app-service

In brief I have some json files which I would like to have publicly available as databases for anyone to make queries on. The querying should be via a REST API. All this needs to be done using Azure.

What might be the fastest/simplest way of doing this? I have researched things like json-server, Azure's Cosmos DB, and so on, but everything seems to be either not what I'm asking for or way too much.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Azure Blob Storage? Each of the blobs is essentially a file that is stored in Azure which you can house Json data. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/

Then you can layer NoDb (https://github.com/cloudscribe/NoDb/blob/master/README.md), or something similar, in a repository on top and expose with Web API. You will need to write a custom storage path resolver  to connect to Azure (https://github.com/cloudscribe/cloudscribe.SimpleContent/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.SimpleContent.Storage.NoDb/PostStoragePathResolver.cs). This approach would not scale very well for high throughput applications but could be switched out for EF and a bigger document store (i.e. CosmosDb) later without having to adjust your API layer.